# Is Sending videos in chat supported in appcelerator

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I want to make an app in which i would want to make a chat module and i want to add sending videos in that application, How ever i want to use appcelerator to build this mobile app as it might take considerably less amount of time , but i dont know if appcelerator supports such complex works 
can some one please tell me if this is possible in titanium , some other modules inclde , 
android caleneder , 
complex ui 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... chat is not supported in Appcelerator - not because it's not possible, but because it's not a native UI control. Appcelerator allows you to write apps using javascript that translates to NATIVE controls being displayed on the screen.

Appcelerator also allows you to write your own custom modules per platform (http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/10/module-development-guide-reference-module-for-ios-and-android/) wither in java or objective-c.

If you want a chat - you can build one using native controls. Want to add pictures and video to it? up to you - you can.

Even in native java and obj-c you'd have to do it and there's no out-of-the-box solution.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Im little late on this, but this should help others. May you check this: https://gist.github.com/dawsontoth/832488